# Intergate Salesforce with BOX without login

Tags: apex, visualforce, integration

I have a `visualforce` page that integrate with `BOX` using `Access_token`, `cliend_Id` and `client_secret`.
the `Access_Token` and `Refresh_token` are updated every 30 minutes by a `Schedule Apex JOB`.

The `visualforce` page is loading `BOX` inside an `iframe`. This is the `iframe tag`

```
<iframe  src="https://app.box.com/embed_widget/s/{!visibleFolder}?show_parent_path=yes&view=list&sort=date&theme=gray&show_item_feed_actions=no&view_file_only=yes" width="100%" height="400" frameborder="0" style="position: relative; top: 0px"/>
```

`visibleFolder` is actually a function that get a **sharing link** from `BOX` which is valid for one day:

```
public void getVisibleFolder(){
    visibleFolder = BoxApi.createFolderSharedLink('4115644933', System.now());
}
```

and **`createFolderSharedLink`** is function in `BoxApi` class :

```
public static String createFolderSharedLink(String folderId, Datetime unshared_at){
    String response = null;
    String requestBody = '{"shared_link": {"access": "open"' + (unshared_at != null? ', "unshared_at": "' + unshared_at.format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss') + '"' : '') + '}}';
    
    HttpResponse res = BoxAPI.request('https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/'+folderId, 'PUT', requestBody, true);
    
    if(res.getStatusCode() == 200){
        Map<String, Object> body = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
        Map<String, Object> shared_link = (Map<String, Object>)body.get('shared_link');
        response = ((String)shared_link.get('url')).substringAfterLast('/');
    }
    return response;
}
```

All works fine, but the problem is that when i access the `my visualforce` page, it still gives me the login and Register buttons, like this :

[image]

and what i need is to be logged in directly when accessing the `visualforce` page without having to enter the username and password, just like this :

[image]

The reason i want to do this, is that we have one user in our Box environment, and lot of users who should access `BOX`, and **we cannot provide all the users with BOX credentials**.

Thank you for your help

Comment: How are you showing this in the VisualForce page? Means can you please share the flow you are using to get the access token.
Are you loading the Box inside iframe if not then how you took these screen shots?

Comment: I will update my question...

Comment: Also, do share the relevant code.

Comment: i updated the question, and i included relevant code from visualforce and apex

Comment: This will always show you the login button because the user is not actually logged in the user is just viewing a shared folder with the required tokens in the URL.

Comment: is There a way to login automatically ?

Comment: What If I say no?